# Updating Context in Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

I am writing a method that it first will retrieve the current context from the model then using context.update() to add on new values for the context. I also tried to use the current method  self.with_context() but still no success since the context values seem frozen and could not be passed in. I read online from some source that there is a way to override the name_get(). But the source only briefly reference, there would be no clear instruction so that i can follow. I am new in Odoo and the problem between v7 and v8 its killing me. Please help me revise my following source code:

> ```
> def get_print_report(self):
>     domain = [('effective_date', '>=', self.from_date),
>               ('effective_date', '<=', self.to_date),
>               ('employee_id', 'in', self.employee_ids.ids),
>               ('department_id', '=', self.department_id.id),
>               ('job_id', '=', self.job_id.id)]
>     list_view = self.env.ref(
>         'trainingwagekp.payroll_wage_hist_wizard_tree_view')
>     context = self._context.copy()
>     if context is None:
>         context = {}
>     if context.get('order_by', False):
>         context.update({'default_order': self.order_by + ' desc'})
>     self.with_context(context)
>     print '===============', self._context
>     return{'name': 'Wage History Report',
>            'view_type': 'form',
>            'view_mode': 'tree',
>            'view_id': list_view.id,
>            'res_model': 'trobz.payroll.wage.history',
>            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
>            'context': context,
>            'domain': domain,
>            }
> ```

Please also let me know which is the best way to modify context in Odoo 8. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You already passing new context in return. Just remove self.with_context(context) line. As per below code.

```
def get_print_report(self):
domain = [('effective_date', '>=', self.from_date),
          ('effective_date', '<=', self.to_date),
          ('employee_id', 'in', self.employee_ids.ids),
          ('department_id', '=', self.department_id.id),
          ('job_id', '=', self.job_id.id)]
list_view = self.env.ref(
    'trainingwagekp.payroll_wage_hist_wizard_tree_view')
context = self._context.copy()
if context is None:
    context = {}
if context.get('order_by', False):
    context.update({'default_order': self.order_by + ' desc'})
return{'name': 'Wage History Report',
       'view_type': 'form',
       'view_mode': 'tree',
       'view_id': list_view.id,
       'res_model': 'trobz.payroll.wage.history',
       'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
       'context': context,
       'domain': domain,
       }
```

Comment: it did not work. i tried many different approaches but the context still wont accept the new values. Sorry my code was not clear. the code meant that i have tried both the old api (context.update()) with the new way self.with_context(). Is there another way?

Comment: Hello, where you want this new context value ?

Comment: The context here i want to be in the wizard in which, after i clicked the 'Print' button, the wizard will return for me the list of required value. However, i found out the way the unfroze the context by setting its attributes skip_invert = False. From there, my context will accept the new values i have added to it then i just search for the context in my search method and process it. My question right now is there a way to access any context in Tree View ? such as Sort by Order context ?

Comment: Have you tried     self = self.with_context(context)?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you check the type of context, you will find that it is a frozen dict. You shall change it to a dict `context = dict(self._context)` then do all the alteration you need then turn it back into a frozen dict and give